# AngularJS views not working

Tags: angularjs, view

this is my project structure

[image]

the view "index.cshtml" works just fine but if I create a view in /Views/Home and I open it, I get the following error:

[image]

How to resolve this?

Comment: which view you are creating and do you add method to return view in controller name Home.

Comment: You requested url should be /Home/Index assuming you have created Index action returning InexView in HomeController

Comment: This is not Angular views... This is views of Razor engine. You working with ASP.NET MVC... If you want to use Angular routing instead, add index.html , add all references of angular, create views folder and use angular routing

Comment: @OlegYudovich thank you for clarifying that. In fact I've been working with Angular for less than a week, so I'm still getting used to it.